# Change Font Size on Blog (Twenty Twelve)

Tags: theme-twenty-twelve

I have a Twenty Twelve child theme. I love the fonts on the site. I am willing to live with the normal font size that Twenty Twelve has on pages like the home page. However, on pages like the blog, I want to have a nice big font that is easy to read (see the size on Medium.com).
The questions is how do I increase the font size on the blog posts only, and not the rest of the site.
Thanks in advance,
Shaan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add those styles with the CSS class `.single` or `.single-post`. Because it's a child theme you'll probably need to use `!important`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I feel that I might make the font size increase site wide (I know how to do that), but I would have to see. Thanks again.